# How to count the total number of words from all the files in a directory?

Tags: users

It could be with anything: terminal, Vim, Atom. How to count the total number of words from all the files in a directory?

Comment: So you want the sum of the word count of all text files in a directory? Recursively or or just flat directly in the folder? How to treat binary files?

Answer (score 6):

If you just want the total number of words in all the files in a directory (and assuming no sub directories, ignoring hidden files and other caveats), you could try:

```
cat * | wc -w
```

`cat *` simply concatenates the content of all the files in the current directory to standard output. This is piped into `wc -w` wc (word count) simply returns the number of words that (in this case) it reads from standard input.

If you're ok with slightly more complex output, simply try:

```
wc -w *
```

wc has other options that return number or lines, number of characters etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
find . -type f -exec wc -w {} + | tail -n1
```

Sample output:

```
 % find . -type f -exec wc -w {} + | tail -n1
 8704 total
```

Tested on Debian Buster (10.5) with

```
 % find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.6.0.225-235f
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec wc -w {} \;
```